# Java add javax.persistence in IntelliJ

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, intellij-idea

I am trying to create a basic Java Spring program. Where do I get javax.persistence? It cannot resolve persistence, and cannot Find JAR on Web after attempting. Currently using IntelliJ .

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

```
package payroll;

import java.util.Objects;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
class Employee {

  private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
  private String name;
  private String role;
```

[image]

Comment: Look at the section "Getting Started" in the tutorial - it says add the following dependencies - Web, JPA, H2. If you performed this step, you will see them in the POM file of your project. If you have already added them, then in IntelliJ, right click on project -> select "Maven" -> "Reload Project"

Comment: If you already check the dependencies. You can [clear IntelliJ cache](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/invalidate-caches.html).

Comment: Which version of spring-boot are you using? Are you taking into account the jakarta namespace change?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That dependency comes from the [`spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-starters/spring-boot-starter-data-jpa).

Please review the suggested dependencies in the tutorial (jpa, web, h2).

If you're using [Gradle](https://start.spring.io/#!type=gradle-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.6&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=data-jpa,web,h2) you should have:

```
dependencies {
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
  implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
  runtimeOnly 'com.h2database:h2'
  testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}
```

Or [Maven](https://start.spring.io/#!type=maven-project&language=java&platformVersion=3.0.6&packaging=jar&jvmVersion=17&groupId=com.example&artifactId=demo&name=demo&description=Demo%20project%20for%20Spring%20Boot&packageName=com.example.demo&dependencies=data-jpa,web,h2):

```xml
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
      <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```